# How to query for count of dates in Google Docs?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a Google Spreadsheet of line items.  One of the columns is a Date field.  How can I query (or use a formula) to, for example, get the count of records where the Date field is within February of 2011?

Note:  Could use a better title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use 2 formulas.

- Create a month column and use the following formula to "display" the month and year:

  `=text(B1,"mmmm YYYY")`

I assumed that the data was in column B, you will need to adjust accordingly. Copy this formula down the entire column

- Create a column to hold the labels for the calculation.
- Put the value for each month in the cells (January 2011, February 2011...)
- Create another column to hold the results, you will need to put the following formula into the cell next to the January 2011 label:

  `=countif(C:C,D1)`

I assumed that the labels are in column D and the results of the text formula are in column C, you will have to adjust accordingly. Copy this formula into the rest of the cells next to the labels.

`countif()` is a very useful formula. The key to this was the use of the text command to generate a result just showing month and year.